# Apache not forwarding to HAProxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, haproxy, stunnel

Scenario:

I have a mobile application that needs to talk to a service hosted by an IBM Datapower appliance.  However, the Datapower appliance requires bi-directional SSL and that will not work for the mobile app. So, my solution was to run an intermediate server using Apache/mod_ssl (with ssl termination) and from there, forward the service request to the Datapower appliance.  However, Apache would not be able to do the bi-directional SSL conversation with the Datapower appliance.  I installed HAProxy to listen locally for the Apache forward of the service request and have HAProxy do the bi-directional SSL conversation with DataPower (using stunnel as a virtual server for HAProxy) like this:

Mobile App->Apache(mod_ssl)->HAProxy(through stunnel)->Datapower

Question:

My issue seems to be that Apache is either not forwarding the transaction to HAProxy or I don't have HAProxy configured correct to listen for the request.  My HAProxy configuration looks like this:

```
######## The first public address as seen by the clients
frontend frt
                                 # address:port to listen to
  bind 127.1.0.1:1
  mode http
  log global                                 # use global log parameters
  option httplog                          # Enable HTTP logging
  maxconn 4000                         # max conn per instance
  timeout client 25s                    # maximum client idle time (ms)
  default_backend bckend_dp   # send everything to this backend by default
```

Thoughts on why HAProxy is not picking up the transaction?  Or, is my entire thought process on how to resolve this dilemma (mobile app talking to DataPower) hosed and I should think of something else?

Comment: You bind line looks weird. Is your IP really 127.1.0.1? Usually you use 127.0.0.1. And port 1 is also unusual.

Comment: I was following an email thread that was posted here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/4111 (scroll towards the bottom).

Comment: Ok, the problem here is you copy and pasted a config without having a minimal understanding of what it means.

Comment: I have more than a minimal understanding of HAProxy except for this one line.  I am unsure of this one line working because, as you pointed out, it is weird.  That is why I was asking the question, this one line is confusing and I was pointing out the link to provide perspective.